# Visualforce Insufficient Privileges - System Admin

Tags: visualforce

I was testing some relatedList functionality in Visualforce, but I keep getting Insufficient Privileges error. I'm logged in as System Admin in a Dev Org. I do have access to the records and their fields manually. System Admin profile also has access all to the VF Pages/Controllers.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" />
    <apex:relatedList list="Contacts" />
    <apex:relatedList list="Cases" />
</apex:page>

**Insufficient Privileges**
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.
```

Comment: Can you check if version settings of vf page and controller are same.

Comment: Yes, they are the same.